# Upload file to Amazon S3 from Android slow

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have implemented the file upload to Amazon S3 following the Amazon guide and I have noticed that it is too slow. It takes around 10 sec to upload a simple png file around 20kb.

Initially I thought that the problem was related with threads and I have implemented an AsyncTask to upload the image, but the problem is still there. Following is the code employed to upload the image.

```
private class UploadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String remotePath;
    String remoteFileName;
    File file;
    Context context;
    S3UploadInterface listener;


    public UploadFileTask(Context context,String remotePath,String remoteFileName, File file, S3UploadInterface listener){
        this.context=context;
        this.remotePath=remotePath;
        this.remoteFileName=remoteFileName;
        this.file=file;
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,
                "MY_PRIVATE_CREDENTIAL",
                Regions.US_EAST_1);
        TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
        Upload upload = transferManager.upload(remotePath, remoteFileName, file);
        TransferProgress transferred = upload.getProgress();
        while (!upload.isDone()) {
            try {
                publishProgress((int) transferred.getPercentTransferred());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                listener.uploadFailed(e);
            }
        }
        return "uploaded";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        if (listener!=null)
            listener.currentUploadProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (listener!=null)
            listener.uploadCompleted();
    }
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks :)

Comment: How do you measure the time? Upload speed may vary depending on the network quality. It's also affected by which endpoint you connect to. For example if you are in Europe and you upload a file to us-east-1 (US Virginia), it can be slow. Choose the endpoint closest to you may increase speed.

Comment: Currently we are in Europe and we have our instances in Virginia. Maybe the problem is  due to the region change, because the posted code is straight forward. In our future plans we will migrate  our instances to Ireland and we will check if the problem persists. I'll keep updated

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon Route 53 (https://aws.amazon.com/route53/)? It's a DNS-based product that allows you to route to the closest available S3 or AWS resource based off of location.

Comment: Yes, in our planned architecture we want to implement de Route 53 to give us more flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to hammer your CPU

```
    while (!upload.isDone()) {
        try {
            publishProgress((int) transferred.getPercentTransferred());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listener.uploadFailed(e);
        }
    }
```

Try adding Thread.sleep to give other threads time to run.

Comment: Good point! I implement the while loop following the amazon S3 documentation, I will try with your solution and check how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @frank is true, even amazon confirms it, check here below "How to Use TransferManager" section.
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1V588RKX5XPQB/TransferManager-for-Android

Comment: The upload may finishes much earlier than the progress bar shows, as the system is busy processing lots of messages in the handler queue.